# How to update local EOS installation?

Tags: development

I installed EOS locally following the instructions here https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/wiki/Local-Environment

Which basically involve:

1. `git clone https://github.com/EOSIO/eos --recursive`
2. `./eosio_build.sh`
3. `sudo make install`

Now suppose some updates to EOS software have occurred (e.g. 1.0.2 to 1.0.3), what is the proper way to update my installation?

Answer (score 2):

Thus far I usually do a:

*git pull*

*./eosio_build.sh*

This might not be the optimal way :)

Comment: Wouldn't you want to do a `git pull`? Because won't git fetch will pull the changes but not apply them to the working directory.  I assume you do a `sudo make install` after?

Comment: Quite so! Thx for discovering my error :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the safest way is to go to the latest branch:

```
git pull
git checkout v1.0.5
git submodule update  --init --recursive
./eosio_build.sh -a “EOS” && cd build && make
```

Then start your nodeos again and you should be updated.

Comment: What does the `-a "EOS"` flag do?

Comment: It builds with EOS as a core symbol, the default is SYS

Comment: I didn't realize that was -a.  I've always seen -s

Answer (score 1):

For now there is no other way to update EOS, the most proper way is doing it again.